# Unexpected JVM Crash at start - Problematic frame readdir_r+0x36 - Apparmor enabled

Tags: java, jvm, apparmor, jfr

**While Apparmor enabled:**

Whenever I start the JVM after turning on the JFR through JVM parameter, the JVM crushes with the following error.

```
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b25 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0xc8556]  readdir_r+0x36
#

...
...

Stack: [0x00007fa86c86f000,0x00007fa86c970000],  sp=0x00007fa86c96eb20,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0xc8556]  readdir_r+0x36
V  [libjvm.so+0x6a73d5]  Jfr::initialize_stage_one()+0xc5
V  [libjvm.so+0x6a8bcf]  JfrActivator::start_stage_one(Thread*)+0xf
V  [libjvm.so+0x6a8e8d]  JfrActivator::on_vm_init(Thread*)+0xcd
V  [libjvm.so+0xa7f8ca]  Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*)+0xc0a
V  [libjvm.so+0x6d8d74]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x74
C  [libjli.so+0x797e]  JavaMain+0x9e
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x76ba]  start_thread+0xca
```

My JFR settings are like:

```
JFR_JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,disk=true,settings=profile,repository=/tmp,maxage=60m,loglevel=info"
```

**When Apparmor is disabled**
JVM starts without any error.

My requirement is, I have to keep Apparmor enabled for my app. How should I get rid of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen for newer versions of JDK 8, or JDK 11?

Comment: I have used jdk1.8 (build 1.8.0_181-b25) only.

Comment: JFR is probably trying to initialize the disk repository (/tmp in your case) or read data from /proc, but Apparmor denies access.